# Getting garbage data when getting data from UDP socket

Tags: python, c++, sockets, jsonparser

So I have a sender program(written in python) that send a API response to this c++ application using UDP socket.

Below is python code that send data :

```py
# Function to send data via UDP socket
def send_data_via_udp(data):
    # UDP server address and port
    udp_server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 12343)  # Change this to your destination UDP server address and port

    # Create a UDP socket
    udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    try:
        # Convert data to JSON string
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        
        # Send data via UDP socket
        udp_socket.sendto(json_data.encode(), udp_server_address)
        
        print("Data sent via UDP successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error while sending data via UDP:", e)
    finally:
        # Close the UDP socket
        udp_socket.close()

data_to_send = {'path': coordinates, 'distance': distance, 'instruction': instruction, 'time': time}
```

Below is the receiver code c++:

```cpp
struct Instruction
{
    int type;
    std::array<uint8_t, 100> instruction;
    std::array<uint8_t, 100> verbal_transition_alert_instruction;
    std::array<uint8_t, 50> verbal_succinct_transition_instruction;
    std::array<uint8_t, 100> verbal_pre_transition_instruction;
    std::array<uint8_t, 100> verbal_post_transition_instruction;
    std::vector<std::string> street_names;
    std::vector<std::string> begin_street_names;
    double time;
    double length;
    double cost;
    int begin_shape_index;
    int end_shape_index;
    std::array<uint8_t, 50> travel_mode;
    std::array<uint8_t, 50> travel_type;
};

// Structure to store the received data
struct ReceivedData
{
    std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> path;
    double distance;
    std::vector<Instruction> instructions;
    double time;
};

// Function to parse JSON data and extract the required fields
ReceivedData parseJsonData(const std::string &jsonData)
{
    ReceivedData data;
    Json::Value root;
    Json::Reader reader;

    // Parse JSON
    if (!reader.parse(jsonData, root))
    {
        std::cerr << "Error parsing JSON data: " << reader.getFormattedErrorMessages() << std::endl;
        return data; // Return empty data in case of parsing error
    }

    try
    {
        // Extract path coordinates
        const Json::Value &pathArray = root["path"];
        for (const auto &coord : pathArray)
        {
            double lat = coord[0].asDouble();
            double lon = coord[1].asDouble();
            data.path.push_back(std::make_pair(lat, lon));
        }

        // Extract distance
        data.distance = root["distance"].asDouble();

        // Extract instructions
        const Json::Value &instructionArray = root["instruction"];
        for (const auto &instr : instructionArray)
        {
            Instruction instruction;
            instruction.type = instr["type"].asInt();
            // Convert JSON strings to std::array<uint8_t, 100>
            std::string instructionStr = instr["instruction"].asString();
            std::copy(instructionStr.begin(), instructionStr.end(), instruction.instruction.begin());

            std::string verbalTransitionAlertStr = instr["verbal_transition_alert_instruction"].asString();
            std::copy(verbalTransitionAlertStr.begin(), verbalTransitionAlertStr.end(), instruction.verbal_transition_alert_instruction.begin());

            std::string verbalSuccinctTransitionStr = instr["verbal_succinct_transition_instruction"].asString();
            std::copy(verbalSuccinctTransitionStr.begin(), verbalSuccinctTransitionStr.end(), instruction.verbal_succinct_transition_instruction.begin());

            std::string verbalPreTransitionStr = instr["verbal_pre_transition_instruction"].asString();
            std::copy(verbalPreTransitionStr.begin(), verbalPreTransitionStr.end(), instruction.verbal_pre_transition_instruction.begin());

            instruction.verbal_post_transition_instruction = stringToArray(instr["verbal_post_transition_instruction"].asString());

            std::copy(verbalPostTransitionStr.begin(), verbalPostTransitionStr.end(), instruction.verbal_post_transition_instruction.begin());
            instruction.verbal_post_transition_instruction[verbalPostTransitionStr.size()] = '\0';

            // for(size_t i = 0; i<verbalPostTransitionStr.size() && i<100; ++i){
            //     instruction.verbal_post_transition_instruction[i] = static_cast<uint8_t>(verbalPostTransitionStr[i]);
            // }
           // std::copy(verbalPostTransitionStr.begin(), verbalPostTransitionStr.end(), instruction.verbal_post_transition_instruction.begin());
            //instruction.verbal_post_transition_instruction[verbalPostTransitionStr.size()] = '\0';
            // Ensure null-termination

            // if (verbalPostTransitionStr.size() < 100)
            // {
            //     instruction.verbal_post_transition_instruction[verbalPostTransitionStr.size()] = '\0';
            // }

            for (const auto &street : instr["street_names"])
            {
                instruction.street_names.push_back(street.asString());
            }
            for (const auto &begin_street : instr["begin_street_names"])
            {
                instruction.begin_street_names.push_back(begin_street.asString());
            }
            instruction.time = instr["time"].asDouble();
            instruction.length = instr["length"].asDouble();
            instruction.cost = instr["cost"].asDouble();
            instruction.begin_shape_index = instr["begin_shape_index"].asInt();
            instruction.end_shape_index = instr["end_shape_index"].asInt();
            std::string travelModeStr = instr["travel_mode"].asString();
            std::copy(travelModeStr.begin(), travelModeStr.end(), instruction.travel_mode.begin());
            std::string travelTypeStr = instr["travel_type"].asString();
            std::copy(travelTypeStr.begin(), travelTypeStr.end(), instruction.travel_type.begin());


            data.instructions.push_back(instruction);
        }

        // Extract time
        data.time = root["time"].asDouble();
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error extracting data from JSON: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return data;
}

int main()
{
    // Create a UDP socket
    int udpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (udpSocket < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error in socket creation" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Bind the socket to an address and port
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // Bind to any address
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(RECEIVER_PORT);

    if (bind(udpSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Bind failed" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in senderAddr;
    socklen_t senderSize = sizeof(senderAddr);
    char buffer[45008]; // Increase buffer size to accommodate larger JSON data

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Waiting for data..." << std::endl;

        // Wait for data to receive
        ssize_t bytesReceived = recvfrom(udpSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&senderAddr, &senderSize);
        if (bytesReceived < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error in recvfrom()" << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        std::string receivedData(buffer, bytesReceived);
        std::cout << "Received data: " << receivedData << std::endl;

        // Parse received JSON data
        ReceivedData parsedData = parseJsonData(receivedData);

        // Print extracted data
        std::cout << "Path coordinates:" << std::endl;
        for (const auto &coord : parsedData.path)
        {
            std::cout << "(" << coord.first << ", " << coord.second << ")" << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "Distance: " << parsedData.distance << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Instructions:" << std::endl;
        for (const auto &instr : parsedData.instructions)
        {
            std::cout << "Type: " << instr.type << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Instruction: ";
            for (const auto &value : instr.instruction)
            {
                std::cout << static_cast<char>(value);
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::cout << "Verbal Post Transition Instruction: ";

            for (const auto &value : instr.verbal_post_transition_instruction)
            {
                std::cout << static_cast<char>(value);
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            // Print other instruction fields as needed
        }

        std::cout << "Time: " << parsedData.time << std::endl;
    }

    // Close the socket
    close(udpSocket);

    return 0;
}
```

and the output I am getting is below:

```bash
Instruction: Bear left to stay on Mehrauli Gurgaon Road/NH148A.
Verbal Post Transition Instruction: Continue for 400 meters.��"�zU,��,����3
Type: 16
Instruction: Bear left to stay on Mehrauli Gurgaon Road/NH148A.
Verbal Post Transition Instruction: Continue for 30 meters.��"�zU,��,����3
Type: 24
Instruction: Keep left to stay on Mehrauli Gurgaon Road/NH148A.
Verbal Post Transition Instruction: Continue for 200 meters.��"�zU,��,����3
Type: 23
Instruction: Keep right to stay on Mehrauli Gurgaon Road/NH148A.
Verbal Post Transition Instruction: Continue for 100 meters.��"�zU,��,����3
Type: 23
Instruction: Keep right to stay on Mehrauli Gurgaon Road/NH148A.
Verbal Post Transition Instruction: Continue for 2.5 kilometers.��"�zU,��,����3
Type: 23
Instruction: Keep right to stay on Mehrauli Gurgaon Road/NH148A.
Verbal Post Transition Instruction: Continue for 200 meters.rs.��"�zU,��,����3
Type: 23
Instruction: Keep right to take Mehrauli-Gurgaon Road.ad/NH148A.
Verbal Post Transition Instruction: Continue for 80 meters.rs.��"�zU,��,����3
Type: 23
Instruction: Keep right to stay on Mehrauli-Gurgaon Road.NH148A.
Verbal Post Transition Instruction: Continue for 1 kilometer.s.��"�zU,��,����3
Type: 23
Instruction: Keep right to stay on Mehrauli-Gurgaon Road.NH148A.
Verbal Post Transition Instruction: Continue for 3 kilometers..��"�zU,��,����3
```

I am not sure how I am getting this issue, in `struct Instructions` if I use `std::string` instead of `std::array<uint8_t,100>` then it works fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The garbage is not in the socket, it's in the array. You print entire 100 values from the array, but you only set N to have a meaningful value. `std::string` manages its own size, so it knows where is the end and how much to print.

Comment: So what would I do to fix this as I cannot use ```std::string``` here. I have to use the array

Comment: @NITIN then you need to keep track of how many values you actually store in the `std::array`, and do not send more than that. Otherwise, consider using `std::vector` instead

Comment: thanks @RemyLebeau I have make another function ```cpp void stringToCharArray(const std::string &str, std::array<uint8_t, 100> &charArray)
{
    memcpy(charArray.data(), str.c_str(), str.size() + 1); // +1 to include null terminator
}
```
for converting string to charArray and used ```array.data()``` to access it.

Comment: @NITIN That code will have UB by going out of bounds if `str.size() >= charArray.size()`. Using `std::strncpy()` would have been safer. But, it is completely unnecessary to copy a `std::string` into a `std::array` in the first place, you could simply send `str.data()`/`str.c_str()` as-is instead and type-cast it to `(const) uint8_t*` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is here:

```
            for (const auto &value : instr.verbal_post_transition_instruction)
            {
                std::cout << static_cast<char>(value);
            }
```

If the type is `std::array`, then you always print 100 bytes, even if some of them are null or garbage.

If the type is `std::string` and if constructed correctly, it will be null-terminated and the iteration will stop on null.

You either want to stop iterating over `std::array` as soon as you hit null, or just use `std::cout<<array.data()` if the string is always null-terminated.

Comment: `std::string` needs not to be null-terminated (theoretically, in practice I doubt any implementation has non-null terminated strings because it has to implement `c_str()`) and can have nulls in the string. But it will print exactly `size()` characters instead of the entire buffer it may have.

Comment: Also, `std::cout << reinterpret_cast<char*>(array.data())` - `array` is `std::array<std::uint8_t, 100>`. And I'm not sure if the arrays are actually null-terminated - `std::copy` probably doesn't copy null terminator, unless it's somehow in the string before `end()`.

Comment: so what would I do to solve this issue like I cannot use ```std::string``` here I have to use array so like what can be the solution for this 
Like I tried to add a terminating character but it doesn't work
```cpp
            instruction.verbal_post_transition_instruction[verbalPostTransitionStr.size()] = '\0';

```

Comment: @Yksisarvinen since C++11, `std::string` is *required* to be null-terminated. But none of its operations *depend* on it being null-terminated. Only legacy C code depends on that. For instance, a range-for loop works only on iterators, and `std::string` iterators do not include the null terminator.